# grep string and print "string"+"wholeline"

Tags: perl, awk, sed, terminal, grep

I want to grep "some string" and print [(lowercase)string]"\t"[the whole line]" that contains that string.

Input:

```
info1 info2 emaiL@Domain.com 09-03-2023
```

output:

```
email@domain.com"\t"info1 info2 emaiL@Domain.com 09-03-2023
```

I want to do this with most efficient way using only one line. Sed, grep, perl, awk are the things that all I know.
Thank you.

Additional info:

I use the code below to grep emails and make them lowercase:

```
perl -pe 's/[A-Za-z{0-9}._+-]+@[A-Za-z{0-9}.-]+\.[A-Za-z{2-9}]/\L\1$&/'
```

Comment: Is the source from a file or a string?

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
awk -v some_string="emaiL@Domain.com" '$0~some_string{printf("%s\t%s\n", tolower(some_string), $0)}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot going on in that substitution and it fails, so the `-p` just prints the unmodified line.

You have the `\L`, which makes the rest of the string after it lowercase. But, you don't want the original line lowercased, so turn off `\L` with `\E`. And, it's old Perl 4 stuff to use the `\1` backreference on the substitution side. Use `$1` instead:

```
perl -pe 's/[A-Za-z{0-9}._+-]+@[A-Za-z{0-9}.-]+\.[A-Za-z{2-9}]/\L$1\E$_/'
```

The `$&` is just the part of the string that matched. You probably want `$_` there.

But, substitution isn't really suited for this. You are matching the email address, and that's the part the `s///` will change. However, you want to add stuff to the beginning of the line. Instead, use the same pattern to extract the email address. Since the `-p` prints the value of `$_` at the end, get rid of that and use `-n` so you can decide how to print:

```
perl -ne 'print "\L$1\E\t$_" if m/(...)/'
```

Or, as ikegami points out, you can forego the capture and use the entire portion of the string that matched (`$&`):

```
perl -ne 'print "\L$&\E\t$_" if m/.../'
```

It's a bit ugly with the pattern, but we'll work on this:

```
perl -ne 'print "\L$1\E\t$_" if m/([A-Za-z0-9{}._+-]+\@[A-Za-z0-9{}.-]+\.[A-Za-z2-9{}]+)/'
```

Your character class looks a bit odd because you are doing a bit too much work. For example, you have `A-Za-z`, but you can match case-insensitively by adding the `/i` flag to the end:

```
perl -ne 'print "\L$1\E\t$_" if m/([a-z0-9{}._+-]+\@[a-z0-9{}.-]+\.[a-z2-9{}]+)/i'
```

But, the characters `a-z`, `0-9`, and `_` are also what `\w` is under ASCII semantics (the `\a` flag - otherwise you match all sorts of wide characters):

```
perl -ne 'print "\L$1\E\t$_" if m/([\w{}.+-]+\@[a-z0-9{}.-]+\.[a-z2-9{}]+)/ia'
```

You should probably stop here.

### Just for fun

But v5.18 introduced [regex character class sets](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/02/perl-v5-18-adds-character-class-set-operations/), `(?[...])`, where you can add or subtract character classes from each other. For example, the second character class you have is almost `\w` but doesn't have `_`:

```
[a-z0-9{}.-]
```

This is really `\w` with `[_]` removed, which is `\w - [_]`. But it also has for extra characters, so add in another character class to get `\w - [_] + [{}.-]`. All that goes in `(?[ ])`:

```
(?[\w - [_] + [{}.-] ])
```

But you can rewrite this to just subtract from the one character class:

```
(?[ [\w{}.-] - [_] ])
```

You'd end up with with something with a lot of braces, which might be more ugly:

```
perl -ne 'print "\L$1\E\t$_" if m/([\w{}.+-]+\@(?[[\w{}.-] - [_]])+\.(?[[\w{}] - [_01]])+)/ia'
```

Lastly, you have braces in your pattern, but I don't know what you want from those. They are just literal characters inside a character class. If you didn't want those as literals, this reduces a bit further:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\t$_" if m/([\w.+-]+\@(?[[\w.-] - [_]])+\.(?[\w - [_01]])+)/ia'
```

Comment: `perl -ne 'print "\L$1\E\t$_" if m/(...)/ia'` simplifies to `perl -ne 'print "\L$&\E\t$_" if /.../ia'`

Comment: I don't think the curlier are supposed to be kept. (You mentioned that in "just for fun", but not in the main part.)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/[^@]* ([[:alpha:]@.]+).*/\L\1\E\t&/' input_file
email@domain.com        info1 info2 emaiL@Domain.com 09-03-2023
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
echo "info1 info2 emaiL@Domain.com 09-03-2023" |\
awk 'match($0, /([^@ ]+@[^ ]+)/) {print tolower(substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)) "\t" $0}'
email@domain.com    info1 info2 emaiL@Domain.com 09-03-2023
```